# SDL audio streaming callback function never triggered

Tags: audio, mingw, sdl

I'm attempting to stream audio for my C++ application which uses SDL through the mingw32 environment. From my understanding it's a fairly simple affair:

```
extern "C" void audioStep(void* unused, Uint8* stream, int len);

void initAudio()
{
    SDL_AudioSpec* fmt;
    fmt = (SDL_AudioSpec*)malloc(sizeof(SDL_AudioSpec));
    fmt->freq = 22050;
    fmt->format = AUDIO_S16;
    fmt->channels = 1;
    fmt->samples = 8192;
    fmt->callback = audioStep;
    fmt->userdata = NULL;
    SDL_AudioSpec obFmt;

    if (SDL_OpenAudio(fmt, &obFmt) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open audio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_PauseAudio(0);
}

.
.
.

extern "C" void audioStep(void* unused, Uint8* stream, int len)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that `audioStep` never seems to be called. Before `initAudio` is run `SDL_Init` is called with `SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING`. Then graphics are fully initialized (`SDL_SetVideoMode` and such) and then the audio system is initialized with the code above.

Is it possible somehow I compiled SDL without audio support? (Is there a way to check if audio is enabled or if it's using some sort of null audio device?)

Answer (score 1):

I have working code in SDL.NET, so maybe this will help. I found that I had to have a Video window opened:

```
  SdlDotNet.Graphics.Video.SetVideoMode(1, 1);
  SdlDotNet.Audio.Mixer.OpenAudio(stream);
  // BUG: close (or hide) it
  SdlDotNet.Graphics.Video.Close();
```

Otherwise, it would not initialize correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why @audioStep@ should be called if you never Play a Sound? There's nothing to do.

[Using SDL Sound](http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/usingsound.html)

Comment: The callback function should be called to fill the sound buffer, whether one is using SDL's sample playing routines or not. I quote from the page you linked: "The audio won't actually start playing until you call SDL_PauseAudio(0)." And I do so in the above code.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see, where you fill the buffer / start Playing.
I take a look in myApplication and put some printf's inside. My Callback will only be called if I fill the buffer and Start Playing.